# View the source code of a 3rd party plugin?

Tags: plugins

I have added a plugin to my WordPress site. How can I get the source code of this plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some ways how we can **view** the `.php` source code for plugins:

### 1) via `wp-admin` access:

Visit the *Plugins* page and press the *Edit* link beneath the plugin name.

For example if we  want to check out the *bbPress* source:

[image]

this link will take us to:

```
/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php?file=bbpress/bbpress.php
```

We can also visit the `/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php` page and select the plugin to edit.

But this will not work if we got:

```
define ( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true  );
```

in the `wp-config.php` file.

*I don't recommend editing plugin files through this editor. If we break something, we might not be able to access it again through the admin pages.*

### 2) via server access:

On the server hosting our files, we most likely find the plugins under:

```
/path/to/your/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/
```

Note that it's possible to rename the `wp-content` directory through code.

We might need to access the server via ftp, sftp, ssh or through some web file managers.

### 3) via wordpress.org:

If the plugin is avialable on wordpress.org, we can check out the `developers` tab.

For bbPress the path is:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress/developers/
```

and here's the screenshot:

[image: bbPress code]

### 4) via GitHub/BitBucket/... repositories:

Many plugins are available on GitHub or Bitbucket. Even mirrors for the wordpress.org plugin SVN repository.

### 5) via the .zip file:

If you have the .zip file, you can open it and view the source files from there.

*ps: bbPress was just a random plugin that I used for demonstration.*